# How to export a big image?

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

I want to export the imagecollection by 'geemap.ee_export_image_collection_to_drive()', and I got this: Error: Exported image is too big (64240321180032 bytes > 64000000000000). (Error code: 3)

All the images in collection are useful so it's better not to use clip() or reduceRegion().

So how to export an image using geemap.ee_export_image_collection_to_drive() if it is bigger than the max bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 64TB image, that is pretty big. I've never been close to exporting anything that size. You might have run into some EE limitation. I would suggest that you tile your AOI, and make multiple exports. When exporting to Google Drive, if you're image is somewhat big, it'll be exported in tiles to begin with. So if you want a single image, you still have to either merge these tiles or create a VRT.

Still, that size of image lead me to believe that you have done something wrong. If you're sure you haven't, make sure you have enough free space in Google Drive before exporting.

Comment: As you mentioned, I've done something wrong. I did not set the 'geometry' parameter and it exported an global image with other areas black. I don't know why my image geometry became unbounded after some processes. To solve this problem, I had to define a geometry at the beginning. However, I still meet an error said that all the axes lengths should be the same except the cat axis (There is an array image, and I use the arrayCat()). I have checked my code , but failed to find the mistakes, which makes me confused.

Comment: Make a separate post for that question, including the relevant code in the question body as text, make sure a used assets are shared, and include a link to the code editor script.